# JSON, Key-Value-Pairs in Groups to "flat" key-value-pair

Tags: json, jq

Each key of a json should be combinded with `_` (or any valid json symbol). To have a simple key-value list.

I have the following structure. A few json groups (no arrays), in side the groups there are key-value pairs. I need to flat them to a single key-value-list. I tried `jq` but there is only sth. "nested" / "unnested". I do not find sth. about flatten or compaine the keys.

So it should be `"key_subkey_subsubkey": "value"`

```json
{
    "welcome": {
        "title" : "Hello World"
    },
    "block1": {
        "header": "My Header",
        "body": "My BODY of block 1",
        "footer": "My Footer"
    },
    "multi": {
        "level-01-A": {
            "head": "Head Section",
            "foot": "Foot Section"
            "level-02-A": {
                "head": "Head Section Level 2 A",
                "fead": "Foot Section Level 2 A"
            },
            "level-02-B": {
                "head": "Head Section Level 2 B",
                "fead": "Foot Section Level 2 B"
            },
        },
        "level-01-B": {
            "head": "Head Section",
            "foot": "Foot Section"
        }
        "no-level" : "Foo Bar",     
    }
}
```

and I want to have

```json
{
    "welcome_title" : "Hello World",

    "block1_header": "My Header",
    "block1_body": "My BODY of block 1",
    "block1_footer": "My Footer",

    "multi_level-01-A_head": "Head Section",
    "multi_level-01-A_foot": "Foot Section",
        
    "multi_level-01-A_level-02-A_head": "Head Section Level 1 A",
    "multi_level-01-A_level-02-A_fead": "Foot Section Level 1 A",

    "multi_level-01-A_level-02-B_head": "Head Section Level 1 B",
    "multi_level-01-A_level-02-B_fead": "Foot Section Level 1 B",

    "multi_level-01-B_head": "Head Section",
    "multi_level-01-B_foot": "Foot Section",

    "multi_no-level" : "Foo Bar"
}
```

Any idea, what tool i can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[ paths(scalars) as $p | { "key": $p | join("_"), "value": getpath($p) } ] | from_entries
```

Will generate

```json
{
  "welcome_title": "Hello World",
  "block1_header": "My Header",
  "block1_body": "My BODY of block 1",
  "block1_footer": "My Footer",
  "multi_level-01-A_head": "Head Section",
  "multi_level-01-A_foot": "Foot Section",
  "multi_level-01-A_level-02-A_head": "Head Section Level 2 A",
  "multi_level-01-A_level-02-A_fead": "Foot Section Level 2 A",
  "multi_level-01-A_level-02-B_head": "Head Section Level 2 B",
  "multi_level-01-A_level-02-B_fead": "Foot Section Level 2 B",
  "multi_level-01-B_head": "Head Section",
  "multi_level-01-B_foot": "Foot Section",
  "multi_no-level": "Foo Bar"
}
```

As you can test [in this online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/bPOxbPKyFc)

---

> `paths` <sup>[[docs]](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example22)</sup>
>
> paths outputs the paths to all the elements in its input (except it does not output the empty list, representing . itself).
>
> ---
>
> `getpath` <sup>[[docs]](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example24)</sup>
>
> The builtin function getpath outputs the values in . found at each path in PATHS.
>
> ---
>
> `from_entries` <sup>[[docs]](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example27)</sup>
>
> These functions convert between an object and an array of key-value pairs. If to_entries is passed an object, then for each k: v entry in the input, the output array includes {"key": k, "value": v}.

---

So the steps I took are:

1. Get every available (nested) path and hold it in a variable

   ```
   paths(scalars) as $p
   ```
2. Create an object holding the `key` and `value`. We can retreive the value by using `getpath`

   ```
   { "key": $p | join("_"), "value": getpath($p) }
   ```
3. Use `from_entries` to convert to a single object

   ```
   | from_entries
   ```

Comment: Better use `paths(scalars)` instead of `leaf_paths` as it will be removed for being deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, that was fast. What is `leaf_paths`  and `from_entries`? Which of them both is my json input? How would the command be, when my json is in my home-dir with the name input.json (e.g. ~/input.json)

Comment: Was just about to press the save button when quoting the docs, thx for the tip!

Comment: The whole command is `cat ~/input.json | jq '[ paths(scalars) as $p | { "key": $p | join("_"), "value": getpath($p) } ] | from_entries'`